# How to access a static member without having an object (C++)

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

I have two classes, the first one has a static member variable. I want to get the value of that variable in a function of the other class but without passing an object of the first class. So how can I call the get-function of the first class? Example:

```
class c1
{
private:
    static int val;
public:
    int getVal();
};

int c1::val = 0;

c1::getVal()
{
    return val;
}
```

How can I access val without passing an object of c1 to doSomething()?

```
class c2
{
public:
    void doSomething();
};

c2::doSomething()
{
    int someCalculation = getVal();  //doesn't work
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

..in c1...

```
static int getVal()
```

.. in c2...

```
c2::doSomething()
    {
        int someCalculation = c1::getVal();
        ...
    }
```